# Procedure or function insert_azienda has too many arguments specified (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm working on a web application using node.js for the server part and I'm trying to make a post request with RESTED (an extension of mozilla, like postman) for putting the data. When I'm trying to execute my stored procedure I'm getting the following error:

> Procedure or function insert_azienda has too many arguments specified.

This is my stored procedure (Sql Server):

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE insert_azienda
    @nome_azienda nvarchar(50),
    @id_azienda int,
    @tipo nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO  [PortaleVettore DB].[dbo].Azienda
                ([nome_azienda],
                 [id_azienda],
                 [tipo])
        VALUES (@nome_azienda,@id_azienda,@tipo)
END
```

And this is my node.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var sql = require("mssql");
var conn = require("../connection/connect")();

var routes = function ()
{
router.route('/')
        .post(function (req, res) {
            conn.connect().then(function () {
               var transaction = new sql.Transaction(conn);
                transaction.begin().then(function () {
                 var request = new sql.Request(transaction);
                  request.input("nome_azienda", sql.NVarChar(50), req.body.nome_azienda)
                  request.input("id_azienda", sql.Int, req.body.id_azienda)
                  request.input("tipo", sql.NVarChar(50), req.body.tipo)

                    console.log("-----------")

                    console.log(req.body.nome_azienda)
                    console.log(req.body.id_azienda)
                    console.log(req.body.tipo)

                    console.log("-----------")

                    request.execute("insert_azienda").then(function () {

                        transaction.commit().then(function (recordSet) {
                            conn.close();
                            res.status(200).send(req.body);
                        }).catch(function (err) {
                            conn.close();
                            res.status(400).send("Error while inserting data 4");
                        });
                    }).catch(function (err) {
                        conn.close();
                        console.log(err);
                       // console.log(request);
                        res.status(400).send("Error while inserting data 3");
                    });
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    conn.close();
                    res.status(400).send("Error while inserting data 2");
                });
            }).catch(function (err) {
                conn.close();
                res.status(400).send("Error while inserting data 1");
            });
          });
          return router;
    };
module.exports = routes;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of counting.
The error message tells you that the SQL procedure expect a number of parameters and that the calling program gives a different number of parameters.

The solution: Take yourself by the hand and compare the 2 list of parameters, check line by line, check the parameter name on both sides ( 1 char difference and it don't match).